# lidR package (4.0.1) - rumple_index error and 'NA' returned

Tags: r, lidr

I have used this code many times over the past year and am now getting an odd error when I try to calculate rumple index.

Here is a simplified version of the code.

```r
library(lidR)

lidar <-readALSLAS("F:/FSF_lidR/Plot_NLAS/FSF_1_N.las", filter = "-keep_classification 3 4 5 -drop_z_below 0 -drop_z_above 48") # read in clipped plot LAS data

las <-filter_surfacepoints(lidar,1)

ri  <- rumple_index(las$X,las$Y,las$Z)
```

Error message:

> Error in loadNamespace(x): there is no package called ‘geometry’
>
> 'rumple_index' returned NA.

Has there possibly been an update to a supporting package I need to reinstall?  Thanks for any advice or thoughts.

MW

Comment: Have you tried installing the package "geometry"?

Comment: Hi Adam, I didn't see a package called that...but now I do and it solved my issues. I am not sure why I have to load it separately now....but appreciate you pointing out my silly error. Thank you.

Comment: If you look at CRAN, `geometry` is in the Suggests line of the package. So that means it won't load and isn't required for the entire `lidR` package, just parts of it. It's generally good practice when developing a package to notify the user of this when attempting to run a function that needs it. But they didn't here. Regardless, the R error itself tips you off to what the problem is.